# SFTP error : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid server's version string

Tags: session, ssh, version, sftp, jsch

I have the below code to SFTP to a location

```java
public static void putFile(String username, String host, String password, String remotefile,     String localfile){
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    try {
          session = jsch.getSession(username, host, 22);
          session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
          session.setPassword(password);
          session.connect();

          Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
          channel.connect();
          ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
          sftpChannel.put(localfile, remotefile);
          sftpChannel.exit();
          session.disconnect();
     } catch (JSchException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();  
     } catch (SftpException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

I am able to SFTP the document from my local machine using the above code. However when I am trying from a different environment to SFTP to the same location I am getting the follow error.

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: **invalid server's version string** at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:253)

Note : I am using **jsch-0.1.31.jar** file.

on printing out `session.getClientVersion()` I am getting **"SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.31"**.

I tried to upgrade the jar file to **jsch-0.1.51.jar** then `session.getClientVersion()` = **"SSH-1.5-JSCH-0.1.51"** and I am getting the following error

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: **Connection reset** at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:558)

Please can you help me on what parameters should I be looking into and what is causing it to run from my local machine and upload to the same SFTP location and not from other environment?

Comment: Your problem is with the ssh server that you're connecting to. First it sent a server version that Jsch didn't like, and now it's closing the TCP connection which your client makes. What OS is running on the server? What SSH server software is it running? What version is this server software?

Comment: Are you able to connect from the local machine at the same time you fail to connect from the "different environment"? What the "different environment" means actually? Different location? Include some log file, e.g. using any GUI SFTP client. Server's log would help too, at least to see whether a connection attempt from the "different environment" reaches the server at all.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Kenster, the exception is about server's version string, not client's. The *"invalid server's version string"* exception is thrown by following code in `Session.connect`:

```java
if(i==buf.buffer.length ||
   i<7 ||                                      // SSH-1.99 or SSH-2.0
   (buf.buffer[4]=='1' && buf.buffer[6]!='9')  // SSH-1.5
   ){
  throw new JSchException("invalid server's version string");
}
```

First, I would try to connect with some client that logs the version string and see yourself. For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/), search its log for a pattern like:

> . 2014-09-03 17:01:20.596 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

<sup>*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*</sup>

Though possibly it's not about version string at all. I would rather believe the error raised by the new version, the *Connection reset*. The old version may fail to detect that the connection was aborted prematurely and tries to validate some random or incomplete data.

The *Connection reset* may indicate wide variety of different errors

- Server refusing a connection from the other location
- Some firewall or proxy not allowing the connection to pass through